# Are these two sentences equal in meaning?

Tags: grammar, meaning

I want to know if the following two sentence are equal in meaning. If not, what is the difference?

> The sparrow was the highest bird of all
>
> The sparrow was the highest of all the birds

Answer (score 1):

Both are perfectly correct. The difference lies only in style.

> The sparrow was the highest bird of all *(here the word ***birds*** is omitted but understood)*

> The sparrow was the highest of all the birds *(here I would omit ***the*** from 'all the birds', it is not absolutely necessary)*

However, I must say that one would need a rather extraordinary context for this sentence, which would allow you to reasonably describe a bird, and a sparrow at that (!), as 'high'.

Answer (score 0):

They mean the same thing.  Though, it is unclear what either of them mean.  I guess the sparrow was one of a group of birds, and happened to be flying or perched higher than all the others?

Comment: I vote for the second one.  I think it is a description of where the sparrow is among other birds.